# SQL Query to Count the Number of People who qualify required criteria

Tags: sql

I am working on a project that has multiple agents and members. Now I have to do the following (through a SQL Query):

1. Select agents and members under a Parent Agent who have made payments, in full (amounting to total of 430, i.e. 130+150+150) for 3 months.
2. Each Agent has n-number of members, so for each agent I need to check if all the members have paid their 3month dues.
3. If dues are paid, return the total member count agent wise for the parent agent.

I have tried the following query, but no luck:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlipDetails](
    [SlipDetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SlipID] [int] NULL,
    [SlipNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberID] [int] NULL,
    [MemberName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MonthID] [int] NULL,
    [MonthAmount] [int] NULL,
    [LateFine] [int] NULL,
    [SubmittedDateByAgent] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApprovedByAdmin] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ApprovedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [MonthName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Blocked] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SlipDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SlipDetailsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberMaster](
    [MemberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberMobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberEmail] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberDOB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberDOJ] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberGender] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberGenderID] [int] NULL,
    [MemberAddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MemberPhoto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsFreeGift] [int] NULL,
    [GiftID] [int] NULL,
    [GiftName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentID] [int] NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CardID] [int] NULL,
    [CardNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SID] [int] NULL,
    [SName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Custom1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Custom2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [IsBlocked] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MemberMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MemberID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgentMaster](
    [AgentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentUserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentPassword] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ParentAgentID] [int] NULL,
    [ParentAgentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BankName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountHolderName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IFSC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BranchName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AgentPhoto] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DOJ] [datetime] NULL,
    [SelectedInDraw] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgentMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AgentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image: Table Structure]

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(dbo.MemberMaster.MemberID) AS CMemberID
FROM dbo.SlipDetails
     INNER JOIN dbo.MemberMaster ON dbo.SlipDetails.MemberID = dbo.MemberMaster.MemberID
WHERE dbo.MemberMaster.AgentID = 203
GROUP BY dbo.MemberMaster.AgentID,
         dbo.SlipDetails.MonthAmount
HAVING(SUM(dbo.SlipDetails.MonthAmount) >= 430);
```

How do I get the Exact Count for the members under each agent? Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you provide some sample/example of result table that you wand to see?

Comment: I want to output in this way
[See Image](https://ibb.co/efdY0n)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: You want table structure here but can't post here because the limit is only 273 char here.

Comment: Table structure should appear in your question.

Comment: Please check  question, posted table structure in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select mm.AgentName,Count(mm.MemberID) as MemberCount from MemberMaster mm
INNER JOIN
(Select AgentID,MemberId from SlipDetails
group by AgentID,MemberID
having Sum(MonthAmount)>=430)sd
on sd.AgentID=mm.AgentID and sd.MemberID=mm.MemberID
Group by mm.AgentID, mm.AgentName
```

or even:

```
Select am.AgentName,MemberCount from AgentMaster am
inner join
(Select mm.AgentID,Count(mm.MemberID) as MemberCount from MemberMaster mm
INNER JOIN
(Select AgentID,MemberId from SlipDetails
group by AgentID,MemberID
having Sum(MonthAmount)>=430)sd
on sd.AgentID=mm.AgentID and sd.MemberID=mm.MemberID
Group by mm.AgentID)mm1
on am.AgentID=mm1.AgentID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    WITH SlipDetails_ttl as (
        Select st.MemberID, sum(MonthAmount) as MonthAmount_ttl 
            from SlipDetails as st
        group by st.MemberID
        having sum(MonthAmount)>=430
    )
    Select am.AgentID, count(stt.MemberID) 
    From SlipDetails_ttl as stt 
    join MemberMaster as mm on mm.MemberID = stt.MemberID
    join AgentMaster as am on mm.AgentID = am.AgentID
    group by am.AgentID
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT agt.AgentID, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.AgentMaster agt -- Get all agents
INNER JOIN dbo.MemberMaster mbr ON agt.AgentID = mbr.AgentID -- Get each agents' members
INNER JOIN dbo.SlipDetails slp ON mbr.MemberID = slp.MemberID -- Get payment details for members
GROUP BY agt.AgentID
HAVING(SUM(slp.MonthAmount)) = 430 -- Only return members that have paid 430
```

A few assumptions/notes:

- only looks at each agent's immediate members (not recursive, one level only)
- does not factor in 3-month constraint, only checks that 430 has been paid per member

Comment: It working but actually, it's showing additions of Member count. If 69 Member paid in NOV and 54 Members Paid Dec its showing sum of 123. I want the result of who only paid in both months. According to me its show only 54 Member who paid in NOV & DEC.